# Can I put an HTC flip clock on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, htc-one-x, clock

I have an HTC One X and it has the typical HTC flip-clock/weather widget loud and proud on the home screen.

I don't really want it there because it's a bit bulky but it would be nice on the lock screen for when I'm just taking my phone out my pocket to check the time?  Is this possible?  I can find setting to customise the clock on the lock screen but, for some reason, the only clock that list doesn't include is the flip-clock I'm after!

Answer (score 5):

Install [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker). It allows to add homescreen widgets on lockscreen.

**Update:**
HTC widgets can't be added to WidgetLocker, but third-party general widgets can be. So, install Beautiful Widgets app, first. It has exact HTC flip-clock alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sachin.  I'm new to Android.  Perhaps you can explain to me the difference between the clocks it *does* allow me to add and the one it *doesn't*.  Are these not all widgets?

Comment: @thehouse I am unable to understand what you are asking.. WidgetLocker Lockscreen allows you to add homescreen widgets on lockscreen. Flip-clock/weather widget is a homescreen widget. ICS (Android 4.0) has introduced drawer widgets which can't be used by WidgetLocker Lockscreen.

Comment: Default lockscreen of HTC sense doesn't allows you to add homescreen widgets. So that I am suggesting to replace it with WidgetLocker Lockscreen.

Comment: The flip clock is a sense widget that can be only added to the sense launcher. ( The Widgetlocker tutorial mentions this too). Also what are drawer widgets? ICS only added a new **way** to add them not a new type.

Comment: So it turns out WidgetLocker doesn't solve the problem.  I can put widgets on the lock screen but still not the HTC flip clock one

Comment: @thehouse Updated the answer.